# while installing eclipse in mac .it is saying change your network connections.what should i do now?

Tags: eclipse, oomph

[image]

While installing eclipse in mac there was a pop up like this. What should I do now?

I selected the local host option and then I pressed ok. But nothing worked

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The Eclipse Installer needs internet access to download the things to install, but in your case it seems it has not internet access (maybe a proxy, firewall, etc. blocks it). If you are unable to give the Eclipse Installer internet access (in the dialog that is shown in the screenshot you can configure to use a proxy; did you try set _Active Provider_ to _Native_?). Otherwise, [download a Eclipse IDE package directly](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/) instead of using the Eclipse Installer.

Comment: which options should i select to configure proxy settings @greg-449

Comment: I don't know what settings you need, it depends on your network setup.

Comment: If you do not know these things about your network you might want to get a traditional zip-file distribution instead.